# Getting the current position of a list element

Tags: haskell

I was wondering if there is a way find out where the list position x is at in a function?

```
hep list = [if x=="you" then "u" else if x=="are" then "r" else x | x <- list]
```

Something like:

```
hep list = [if x=="by" && elemAt(x+1)=="the" && elemAt(x+2)=="way" then "btw" else if x=="are" then "r" else x | x <- list]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably don't want to solve your problem this way (indexing into linked lists being an algorithm smell and all), but if you really need indices you can get them by zipping against a list of indices:

```
zip [0..] some_list
```

Then, as you traverse this new list, you will get pairs instead of single elements.  The first element of each pair will be the index that you want, the second element will be the item.

Or perhaps you are asking what function you use to go the other way (to get the element at some index)?  For that you use `!!`:

```
some_list !! 5
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I appreciate the suggestion, however, this is not what I was looking for, thanks anyways though.

Comment: @MHZ how is this not what you're looking for?  Details.

Comment: How is it? Explain. You did not really explain how it can be applied to my problem, you just showed me how to use zip, which I already know how to do :D

Comment: @MHZ He told you how to get the index by using `zip`, which is what you asked.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the index by zipping the given list with `[0..]`, but accessing list items by index is neither an idiomatic nor an efficient way to do what you want to do.

A better solution would be to use recursion and pattern matching to iterate over the list, taking multiple elements at once.

Comment: How would recursion be used to take multiple elements at once, in this case?

Comment: @MHZ You pattern match to see whether the first elements of the list are any of the word combinations you're looking for and then you recurse on the remaining elements.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on sepp2k's answer, you could try something like this:

```
hep ("by" : "the" : "way" : rest) = "btw" : hep rest
hep ("are" : rest)                = "r"   : hep rest
hep (yadda : rest)                = yadda : hep rest
hep []                            = []
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not familiar with this syntax, can you please explain what it is your code does?

Comment: Everything to the left of the equals signs is [pattern matching](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions); to the right I build the list using [the cons operator and the empty list](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#an-intro-to-lists). (Sorry I am not able to link to precisely the parts of the pages I wish to: you will need to read down a little.)